# How to hide All section header in UITableViewcell (grouped style)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, height

I have two section in `UITableviewCell`. I want hide that two section.
this is my code.

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section == 0)
{
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
else
{
    return 32.0f;
}
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return [storename2 count];
}

 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewtitleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section == 0)
{
    return nil;
}
else
{
     return [storename2 objectAtIndex:section];
}
}
```

In Viewdidload.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 self->CartTableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0);
}
```

But its only Hide First Section,
show below image i want like this (When Card Is Empty Hide Sections and when i add products to the card show all(two)section.)
help me,

show 1st image.
when i add product to card two section will show and when i remove the product all section will hidden.
Thanks in Advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It works for me that returning 0.1 for sectionHeader height.

Answer (score 1):

Also don't forget to set UITableview Delegate & datasource.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0);
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Specific section
    if (section == 0)
            return 0.0f;

    // all sections
    return 0;
}

- (NSString*) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   // Specific section
    if (section == 0) {
        return nil;
    } else {
    // all sections
        // return some string here ...
    return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make it clear what do you want to hide here (in your image) 1. A view with sky blue background and title delivery charges or 2. a white view with several gray lines (coveting background in center) or 3.bottom blue area (view) with title checkout?

Comment: Yes but what your sections in this image. A view with sky blue background and title delivery charges is section or you have added separate view?  a white view with several gray lines (coveting background in center) are row separators (indicating rows), not sections. Pl. make it clear, what your sections in this image

Comment: Sry for your trouble,i'm new in ios.

Comment: Np, just let me know, what are sections in this image

Comment: Yes, that's... I was right, they are you tableview row separators. At this point (when your table/cart is empty) hide your table or remove row separators from tableview.

Comment: below delivery charge .. Lebanese Taverna & babylon Market are Section.
And Creamy Swiss Light Cheese(Image and value included) are product which i added..

Answer (score 1):

Just return 0 in heightForHeaderInSection tableview delegate method...

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Specific section
    if (section == 0)
            return 0.0f;

    // all sections
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need change in bellow method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

And Remove this method

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewtitleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if (section == 0)
   {
     return nil;
   }
   else
   {
     return [storename2 objectAtIndex:section];
   }
}
```

This will hide all the section header in your tableview.

Comment: How you are identify the that your cart is empty?, or give me your array name then i can add condition over there

Answer (score 0):

Use switch-case to handle multiple section height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    let headerHeight: CGFloat

    switch section {

    case 0:
        // first section for test - set value for height
        headerHeight = 0

    default:
        // other Sections - set value for height
        headerHeight = 0
    }

    return headerHeight
}
```